# Windows command to identify chipset of USB wifi dongle?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, usb

Is there a simple way in Windows to find the chipset used on a USB wifi dongle?

I need someone remote to run a command and tell me what hardware he has on his computer; As he is barely computer-literate, I need the simplest solution.

I tried [Speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy), but it doesn't provide enough information (and requires installing an application.)

Thank you.

---

Edit: "msinfo32.exe" provides the infos I was looking for.

Comment: Just to clarify, does it have to be a command? Or will UI methods work?

Comment: UI is simpler, but CLI is Ok

Comment: Does Device Manager + http://pcidatabase.com/ help?

Comment: No, it doesn't display the chipset… but msinfo32.exe does :-) Thank you.

Comment: Please post that as an answer. You'll be able to mark it as a solution and the question will appear as resolved to others.